# Why are Eurodollar futures settled to 100 minus LIBOR? Is this actually connected to a Eurodollar depsoit?

Tags: libor, eurodollars

I'm confused as to why Eurodollar futures prices settle to $100-LIBOR$ at expiration. If at the time of settlement the futures contract was meant to represent a 1,000,000 Eurodollar deposit to mature 3 months in the future, then wouldn't we discount the 1,000,000 back to today to get the settlement price. This would mean the futures contract would settle to $\frac{1,000,000}{1 + LIBOR/4}$. Where does $100-LIBOR$ come from? Is this just a convention for how to settle the contracts, meaning Eurodollar futures have nothing to do with any underlying Eurodollar deposit?

Comment: It is just a pricing convention. What matters is LIBOR, i.e. the rate on eurodollar deposits. But in fixed income we are used to the convention "when interest rates go up prices go down"; so the "price" was defined as 100-LIBOR so that this general rule is maintained. So if you buy the future at 98 and it settles at 99 you made money because LIBOR went down and price went up, just like when you buy a bond or any other fixed income security

Comment: And you are correct, the contract itself does not have an underlying deposit.  It is pure cash settle.